# How to shorten URL pointing to my server (NOT MOBILE APP)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase-dynamic-links, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

I am working on a mobile app and I want to be able to generate several short urls and share to users without showing my actual url with server name.

The long URLS have parameters to certain resources. Server is hosted in **Google App Engine** and written in **nodejs**

Which is the best and **safe** way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebase Dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create?authuser=0)  has solved my problem